# Find all mp3 files in a directory by php

Tags: php

Is there any way that php can find all the mp3 files in a directory(even inside sub directories)?
So you don't have to find them manually and you can add music easier?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) function:

```
print_r(glob("*.mp3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all files including sub-directories.

$Regex will have single index array of all files you need.

```
<?php    
$Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/project/');
$Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);
$Regex = new RegexIterator($Iterator, '/^.+\.mp3$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
?>
```